# How to call Facebook Pixel Event from AngularJS controller?

Tags: angularjs, facebook-ads-api

I want to track conversion of a Facebook Ad. Therefore I need to call

```
fbq('track', 'CustomerRegistration');
```

in the signup result page but I don't have one. User is redirected to the dashboard after successful signup. So I need to call `fbq` from the controller.

How can I do that? Is it a good way?

Comment: if it's globally defined, you can call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `$window`: `$window.fbq('track', 'CustomerRegistration');`